# Kelvin's Circulation theorem applied to a cup of tea

Tags: fluid-mechanics, aerospace-engineering, aerodynamics

Recently, I dipped my spoon into my tea. I saw that as I dipped my spoon into my tea, two vortices formed at both edges of the spoon. I guess this is similar to vortices forming at the end of aeroplane wings. Here I assume both vortices have equal strength and according to Kelvin's circulation theorem, the sum of circulation must equal zero in my system (my cup of tea).

However, I noticed that if I stirred my tea first and then dipped my spoon into my tea (whilst the fluid was rotating), two vortices would still form (for a very short period of time) and then they would combine together (since the fluid was still rotating from when I stirred my tea). They would form one vortex. However, I would like to ask why the two vortices don't cancel out? Are they not of equal strength?

Comment: prior to dipping, did the velocity of the tea vary vs r (r measured from the cup's axis of symmetry)?

Comment: A cup of tea aka "a strong brownian motion producer"…

Comment: The decay of vortices is a viscosity thing. If the vortices are not symmetrical, and they won't be, they will decay differently in that very constrained space.

Comment: Also, in a teacup, Poincare's circulation theorem is more on target. Compared to an irrotational vortex (stirred frictionless teacup), the real one will look more like an irrotational vortex + a fixed rotation in the opposite direction (due to wall friction). And in Poincare's theorem, the conserved term is more complicated. Loop circulation itself isn't conserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding the circulation of the tea when you stirred it was not zero.  So the vortex that formed from the two smaller one must have had the same direction of the initial stir.

I would consider that they *if* there is any difference in vorticity "strength" is probably due to viscous phenomena when the spoon gets inside a fluid which is moving and there are trailing detachment vortices.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to "see" your experience without pictures.

First, when you inserted your spoon, you could have lowered it at an angle causing it to displace the liquid like a row causing two trailing vortices at the edges.

Later when you dipped it into circulating tea, the current interacted with the two vortices. The current would accentuate and pull in a vortex rotating in the same direction concentrically, and repel the other vortex, hence merging them.